# How can I delete a tag?

Tags: support, tags

I accidentally created a tag ([ve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ve)), How do I delete it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *can't* directly delete a tag. The process to remove one *(not having it appear as a suggestion)* is that you untag it from any question(s) that it was attached to and the system will remove it after a while.

*IIRC*.. the tag script runs daily so any orphaned tags *(those not attached to a question)* will automatically be removed provided no one uses it in that space of time.

Also see [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags)